# What is corporate directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-authenticator

I san in [aws iam docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction_identity-management.html)

> If your **corporate directory** is compatible with Security Assertion Markup Language 2.0 (SAML 2.0), you can configure your corporate directory to provide single-sign on (SSO) access to the AWS Management Console for your users.

Comment: That is the "directory of user information" of your company, e.g. keycloak, AD, ...

Comment: Basically it's a file(i.e, Active Directory) that defines structure of your organization in terms of group/users and you can use that to authenticate users against AWS and also define authorization levels in AWS assigned to those users/groups.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, 
Is it like like a wrapper around csv + rest for talking another programs or is it single source of truth for every authentication and authorization.

Comment: See [Directory service - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service) and [Active Directory - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory).